# Sorting an array of objects does not sort all items correctly by date in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array that has several objects as below:

```
{
    FormaPagto: "Online com cartão de crédito"
    Servico: "Barba (Alinhamento)"
    apelido: "Beatrice"
    dt_extrato: "2020-07-02T00:00:00"
    dt_inicio: "2020-07-02T11:55:00"
    fechamento_tipo: null
    nome: "Beatrice Mattos"
    salaoNome: "Beauty Salon - Salão Piloto"
    vlr_consumo: 0
    vlr_desconto: null
    vlr_pago: null
    vlr_prof: 1.2
    vlr_salao: 4.8
    vlr_servico: 6
}
```

I order this array as follows:

```
    array.sort(this.sortByDate);
```

Sorting function:

```
    sortByDate(init, prox) {

    var dataInit = new Date(init.dt_inicio);
    var dataProx = new Date(prox.dt_inicio);

    if (dataInit.getTime() < dataProx.getTime()) {
      return -1;
    } else if (dataInit.getTime() > dataProx.getTime()) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

However, when I order this array 3 elements inside it are cluttered in the html, but the array in the console is ordered correctly. Follows html image, marking the disordered elements.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXThp.jpg)

Would anyone know what this could be?

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to help you with the limited info you have provided. Maybe create a StackBlitz that replicates the issue.

Comment: sorting an array will not affect the order in the DOM

Comment: I showed you how my list is, and the function I use to sort it, what more information do you need?

Comment: how you display it. My guess is you are sorting the array too late to affect what you see in the browser

Comment: Could you provide the sample data in your image? I think 2 fields should be enough (nome and dt_inicio)

Comment: name of the key of the date, on which u want to sort.